# CodeIgniter email client From display name is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter is not able to  show “From” display name

```
$from_email = 'abcXXXX@XXXX.com';
$from_name = 'John smith';
$this->email->from($from_email, $from_name );
```

It shows only the email address or the email from name set in the office 365 display name

Comment: Check the email headers to see if `From` is being correctly sent. If it is, I'd bet that Office 365 is overriding it to prevent things like `From: PayPal <not-really-paypal@gmail.com>` phishing attacks.

Comment: @ceejayoz it shows same in all email clients like gmail and yahoo too

Comment: Follow the instructions to view the headers in Gmail at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/29436?hl=en. Do you see a `From` header?

Comment: @ceejayoz i checked the headers it shows the default name not the name sent from the php code. i have done a print debug before sending the code it show the correct name but it changes when we send the email

Comment: Your outgoing SMTP server may be enforcing the `From` value. Are you sending via Gmail?

Comment: @ceejayoz i am using office365 stmp to send emails.... only the sender display name is impacted.

Comment: My suspicion is that Office 365 rewrites the `From` when you go through their SMTP servers as an anti-abuse (spam, phishing, etc.) measure. Gmail does a similar thing. Try sending through an email service provider like Sendgrid.

Comment: @ceejayoz you are correct office 365 rewrites the from display name....